# Phase choice for Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm using SingularValueDecomposition to find the unitary matrices that diagonalize a given matrix (that I have). This decomposition is unique, up to multiplication for an arbitrary phase of each column of the left and right unitary matrices. Is there a way to find out how Mathematica chooses this phase, or can I set some condition when using SingularValueDecomposition, for example, to impose that the first column of the left matrix must be real?

Answer (score 3):

I can tell just from experiments: Apparently, the first *row* of `U` is always real:

```
n = 12;
A = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {n, n}];
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A];
Im[U[[1]]]
```

> {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}

As AccidentalFourierTransform pointed out, that means that each left singular value of `A` is normalized to have its first entry being real.

You can also achieve that the first row of `V` (hence the first entry of each right singular vector) is real by apply the following unitary transformation `W`:

```
W = DiagonalMatrix[Exp[-I Arg[V[[1, All]]]]];
Unew = U.W;
Vnew = V.W;
Max@Abs[Unew.S.ConjugateTranspose[Vnew] - A]
Chop[Im[Vnew[[1]]]]
```

> 1.9004*10^-15
>
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Analogously, you can manage to have only real numbers for either all the $i$-th entries of the left singular vectors or all the $j$-th entries of each the right singular vectors.

What probably puzzles you is that *Mathematica* uses the convention

```
U.S.ConjugateTranspose[V] == A
```

instead of

```
ConjugateTranspose[U].S.V == A
```

the latter being prefered in many textbooks because the column vectors of `U` and `V` are then the singular vectors.

Comment: Ok, but this still does not help me: I need the conditions on the columns because those are basically the eigenvectors of the original matrix, and I need to impose some phase conditions on them

Comment: @Alessio Isn't Henrik's answer basically telling you that the convention is that the first component of each eigenvector is taken to be real?